# It says "Multiple choices" in side my second radio button on "onItemSelected", how can i fix?

Tags: java, android

I have 2 radiobuttons and 1 spinner, every radiobutton selected has different value for every item inside Spinner, but when i create my second method "onItemSelected" and "parent" color inside parameter goes red. I think its because word "parent" inside parameter are same with my first method "OnItemSelected". But how can i fix it?

This is my Activity.java

```
    public class Main2Activity extends
    AppCompatActivity implements RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    public TextView ttkalorisehari, ttkaloriseminggu,txtbb;
    double naik_bb, kt;
    Spinner kcpt;
    String[] kecepatan = {"...","Jalan kaki santai (3mph)","Jalan kaki cepat (4mps - 5mmps)", "Jalan kaki menaiki bukit (3,5mph)","Jalan kaki turun bukit (2,5mph)","Naik tangga (3mph)"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    RadioButton umurA, umurB;
    RadioGroup rg;
    Button bhitung;
    double kcptjalan;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();
        ttkalorisehari = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tjml_kal);
        ttkaloriseminggu = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tjml_kal_seminggu);
        txtbb = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tnaik_bb);
        kcpt =(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.kecepatan);
        rg = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rg);
        umurA = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.RA);
        umurB = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.RB);
        bhitung = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnhitung);
        ttkalorisehari.setText(data.getString("kalorisehari"));
        ttkaloriseminggu.setText(data.getString("kaloriseminggu"));
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,kecepatan);
        kcpt.setAdapter(adapter);
        try {
            double nilai_bb = Double.parseDouble(ttkaloriseminggu.getText().toString());
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
            naik_bb = (Double.valueOf(nilai_bb)/7000);
            txtbb.setText(df.format(naik_bb));
        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Isi kolom kosong",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }    
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, @IdRes int checkedId) {
        if(checkedId==R.id.RA){
            kcpt.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    switch (position){
                        case 0:
                            kcptjalan = 0;
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            kcptjalan = 0.3;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            kcptjalan = 0.16;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            kcptjalan = 0.17;
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            kcptjalan = 0.12;
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            kcptjalan = 0.37;
                            break;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });
        }
        if (checkedId==R.id.RB){
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        kcptjalan = 0;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        kcptjalan = 0.23;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        kcptjalan = 0.12;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        kcptjalan = 0.13;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        kcptjalan = 0.13;
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        kcptjalan = 0.27;
                        break;
                }
            }
                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, why don't you just create a function called `onItemSelected()` outside your `onCheckedChanged` method and call it with parameters telling what value to use.

Comment: can u give me example pls, i really new and also still learning about java

Comment: Well if your values don't change, I would probably go for a static array containing every values and accessing the values from that function

Comment: its not about value Sir, its about parent inside parameter of my second `onItemSelected` method, its red and says `bla bla bla multiple choices` but my first `onItemSelected` parent inside parameter isn't Red.

Comment: In the first `if`, you are creating a `new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()` in the `kcpt.setOnItemSelectedListener`, in the second one, you just a have method declaration. Try doing `kcpt.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {` at the start of the second if too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution you might want to consider :

If your values don't need to change and can't be generated in your code, just use an array like so :

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity 
                           implements RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    private static final double[][] values = {{0, 0.3, 0.16, 0.17, 0.12, 0.37},   //first radio button values
                                              {0, 0.23, 0.12, 0.13, 0.13, 0.27}}; //second radio button values

    Spinner kcpt;
    double kcptjalan;
    /*
     * your other attributes...
     **/


    /*
     * your other methods...
     **/

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, @IdRes int checkedId) {
        if(checkedId == R.id.RA){
            kcpt.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    kcptjalan = values[0][position];
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });
        }
        if (checkedId == R.id.RB){
            kcpt.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
                    kcptjalan = values[1][position];
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I would also suggest to refactor this into the following code :

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity 
                           implements RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    private static final double[][] values = {{0, 0.3, 0.16, 0.17, 0.12, 0.37},   //first radio button values
                                              {0, 0.23, 0.12, 0.13, 0.13, 0.27}}; //second radio button values

    Spinner kcpt;
    double kcptjalan;
    /*
     * your other attributes...
     **/


    /*
     * your other methods...
     **/

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, @IdRes int checkedId) {
        if(checkedId == R.id.RA){
            kcpt.setOnItemSelectedListener(getAdapterView(1)});
        } else if (checkedId == R.id.RB){
            kcpt.setOnItemSelectedListener(getAdapterView(1)});
        }
    }

    private OnItemSelectedListener getAdapterView(int index) {
        return new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
                kcptjalan = values[index][position];
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        };
    }
}
```

Since it is actually easier to read and maintain. If you need to add a radio button or something, just change one thing, not the whole thing

Comment: so i dont need to put Switch Case sir?

Comment: Sir did you try your top code in android studio? because i still have a problem with `parent` inside parameter on my second `onItemSelected`, but first `onItemSelected` works well.

Comment: Yes, and I get no error whatsoever. Can you copy your message? maybe the error is somewhere else before this one